# "require" is not defined, but i can't use import, then what should i do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I want to make an application with electron, and i got the same error again:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at render.js:8
```

This is my *render.js* file:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = printlog;

function printlog() {
    console.log('Print')
}

const fs = require('fs');
const folder = './src/';
fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
  });
});
```

This is my *index.js* file: (the main)

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    }
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.
```

And finally, this is my *index.html* file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script defer src="render.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <button id="button">Button</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know any people who knows js, so i asked a discord server, they said, that i need to do type="module" at the index.html at the script, but it still didn't worked.
If i swap it to import, it's still don't want to work, and i have literally no clue how to solve this issue.
Please help me somehow, it feels like i'm stuck with that forever.

Comment: You cannot use require in render.js - you can only use fs in your main process (index.js). Read something about ipcMain and ipcRenderer (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) which allows you to send messages from main process to render.js and give your file

Comment: to clarify, you can use require in renderer, but just not by default.